# How to convert the following lines of code from C to Golang (casting arrays)

Tags: arrays, c, go, casting

I would like to know how to convert the below C code into Golang

The C code:

```
//process the plaintext 
//unsigned int state[4];
//const unsigned char *m
//unsigned char *c
for (i = 0; i < (mlen >> 2); i++)
{
        state[1] ^= FrameBitsPC;
        state_update(state, k, NROUND2);
        state[3] ^= ((unsigned int*)m)[i];
        ((unsigned int*)c)[i] = state[2] ^ ((unsigned int*)m)[i];
}
```

Below is the Golang code (that I have tried):

```
//process the plaintext    
for i := 0; uint64(i) < (mlen >> 2); i++{
        state[1] ^= FrameBitsPC;
        state_update(state, k, NROUND2)
        state[3] ^= uint32(m[i])
        uint32(c[i]) = state[2] ^ uint32((m)[i])        
}
```

I get an error at the last statement saying that you cannot assign a uint32 to c[i]. I would like to know how to overcome this problem.

Comment: try using [GitHub copilot](https://github.com/features/copilot)

Comment: There is no casting in Go. What are the types of `c` and `m` here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if `unsigned char *c` in C code is corresponding to slice or array of `uint8` in Go code then last statement should be:

```
c[i] = uint8(state[2] ^ uint32(m[i]))
```